# Caliburn.micro : Bind two views of ViewModel with tab Control

Tags: caliburn.micro

I  am trying to bind two views of viewmodel to two tabs of tab control by editing sample source code Caliburn.Micro.SimpleMDI included with Caliburn.Micro source. This project contains ShellViewModel and TabViewModel with TabView. I added one View named TabViewDetails. I edited ShellViewModel as follows.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive 
{
    int count = 1;

    public void OpenTab()
    {
        TabViewModel  vm = null;
        if (Items.Count != 0)
        {
            vm = new TabViewModel() { DisplayName = "Detail Tab " + count++ };   
            var secondView = new TabViewDetails();

            ViewModelBinder.Bind(vm, secondView , null);


        }
        else
        {
            vm = new TabViewModel() { DisplayName = "Tab " + count++ }; 
        }

        ActivateItem(vm);
    }

}
```

First tab is Ok. But the second tab shows nothing.Can anybody help to figure out the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Caliburn.Micro much but the simple solution is one view, one view model.  If you change your code to something like:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive {
    int count = 1;

    public void OpenTab()
    {
        Screen screen;

        if (count != 0)
        {
            screen = new TabViewModel
                            {
                                DisplayName = "Tab " + _count++
                            };
        }
        else
        {
            screen = new TestViewModel
                            {
                                DisplayName = "Tab " + _count++
                            };
        }

        ActivateItem(screen);
    }
}
```

where TestViewModel can be a TabViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel : TabViewModel
{
}
```

then this works ok.

The [Caliburn docs](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) does have a section *multiple views over the same viewmodel* but I haven't figured that out yet.